# How to insert two Image field in MS access database using C#?

Tags: c#, database, oledb, sql-insert

I am new to Stackoverflow but I will try my best to convey my problem as clear as I can and you can ask me if you are confused or not clear!

My code is working but I want that some one suggest me the professional and efficient code having same functionality.

My code is all about insertion data in MS access Database table that have two picture fields.

Thanks in Advance

Here is my code:

// Code on insert button click event

```
 private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            var pic = File.ReadAllBytes(imageName);
            var pic1 = File.ReadAllBytes(imageName1);

            OleDbConnection OleDbConn = new OleDbConnection(cs);
            OleDbCommand OleDbComm = new OleDbCommand();
            OleDbComm = OleDbConn.CreateCommand();

            OleDbComm.CommandText = "insert into candidateTB (pollingStationID,candidateName,candidateCNIC,"+
                "candidateCell,gender,candidateEmail,address,description,candidateParty,candidateImage) " +
                "values ( " + textBox2.Text + ",'" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','"+textBox5.Text+"',"+
                "" + comboBox1.Text + ", " +
                    " '" + comboBox6.Text + "','" + textBox7.Text + "' ,'" + textBox8.Text + "', '" + comboBox5.Text + "' "+
                    ", @Photo)";


            OleDbComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Photo", pic);
            OleDbComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Photo1", pic1);

            OleDbConn.Open();
            int x = OleDbComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            OleDbConn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(x.ToString() + ": Record is Successfully Inserted");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

       }
```

// Code for the add picture button 1

```
 try
        {

            FileDialog fldlg = new OpenFileDialog();

            fldlg.Filter = "Image File (*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif)|*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif";
            fldlg.Title = "Select Picture for The Agent.";
            if (fldlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                imageName = fldlg.FileName;
                Bitmap newimg = new Bitmap(imageName);
                pictureBox1.Image = newimg;

            }

            fldlg = null;

        }

        catch (System.ArgumentException ae)
        {

            imageName = " ";

            MessageBox.Show(ae.Message.ToString());

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());

        }
```

//Cide fir button2 to add 2nd picture:

```
        try
        {

            FileDialog fldlg1 = new OpenFileDialog();

            fldlg1.Filter = "Image File (*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif)|*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif";
            fldlg1.Title = "Select Flag For the Candidate party.";
            if (fldlg1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                imageName1 = fldlg1.FileName;
                Bitmap newimg1 = new Bitmap(imageName1);
                pictureBox2.Image = (Image)newimg1;

            }

            fldlg1 = null;

        }

        catch (System.ArgumentException ae)
        {

            imageName1 = " ";

            MessageBox.Show(ae.Message.ToString());

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());

        }
```

Comment: Where is the second picture field in the code above? I see just one for @photo. Apart from this what happen if you candidate name is O'Brian? and finally, have you ever heard about Sql Injection?

Answer (score 1):

To be safe from Sql Injection use parameterized query and To avoid manually `closing` & `disposing` ADO.NET object. use `using` statement.

```
try{

        var pic = File.ReadAllBytes(imageName);
        var pic1 = File.ReadAllBytes(imageName1);

        using(OleDbConnection OleDbConn = new OleDbConnection(cs)){
            using(OleDbCommand OleDbComm = OleDbConn.CreateCommand()){
                //OleDbComm = OleDbConn.CreateCommand();
                OleDbComm.CommandText = "insert into candidateTB (pollingStationID,"+
                                        "candidateName,candidateCNIC,candidateCell,gender,"+
                                        "candidateEmail,address,description,candidateParty,"+
                                        "candidateImage)  Values ( " + 
                                        "@psid,@cname,@ccnic,@ccell,@gender,@email,@address,"+
                                        "@description,@cparty,@Photo)";

                OleDbComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@psid",textBox2.Text);
                OleDbComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cname",textBox3.Text);
                OleDbComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ccnic",textBox4.Text);
                OleDbComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ccell",textBox5.Text);
                OleDbComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender",comboBox1.Text);
                OleDbComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email",comboBox6.Text);
                OleDbComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address",textBox7.Text);
                OleDbComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description",textBox8.Text);
                OleDbComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cparty",comboBox5.Text);
                OleDbComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Photo",pic);
                //OleDbComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Photo1",pic1); I don't know from where it came, I don't see in the insert query.

                OleDbConn.Open();
                int x = OleDbComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //OleDbConn.Close(); you don't need to close it, when the end of using statement is executed it will automatically  be closed & disposed.
                MessageBox.Show(x.ToString() + ": Record is Successfully Inserted");
           }
       }
}
catch (Exception ex){
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

I see some odd stuffs in your code. Like you were taking value of `Email` from ComboBox `comboBox6` and the parameter `@Photo1`. I think you forgot to add it in `insert query`. You need to monitor carefully.

Comment: Check your list of parameters placeholders. You are missing one.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. It was quite confusing with all that texts quotes etc etc

Comment: there is some things wrong in using statements i thing there should one using statement.

Comment: nope. They are fine. One for `OleDbConnection` & One for `OleDbCommand`

Comment: What's the error? This has been done many times. I don't think error is from this one.

Comment: Got it! I missed one parameter for CandidateParty i.e `@cparty` and instead I added `@description` twice. Now try the edited answer. it will work

Comment: cannot assign to oleDBComm because it a using variable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120528/discussion-between-sangeen-and-jonju).